# Query a dblink synonyms would create a transaction( Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production)

Tags: oracle11g, synonym, dblink

In my local oracle server(SID is orcl) ,I create a dblink and create a synonym in this dblink(target SID is dev),the code as follow:

```
create or replace synonym test002 for sys.test2@DBLINK2;
```

When I query this synonym  in **PLSQL Developer**, as follow

```
select * from test002
```

there is no transaction created by querying the v$transaction, as follow

```
select * from v$transaction
```

There is  another remote oracle server, the dblink and synonym is created by dba , 
when I query the synonym in this oracle server with **PLSQL Developer**, there is a transaction created.

I don't know that why there is no transaction created when query the synonym  in my local oracle server, and why there is a transaction created in the remote oracle server .

Comment: What queries are you executing, and how are you looking for a transaction? What versions are the two databases, and the targets of the DB links?

Comment: Hi,@AlexPoole. I've detailed the environment, if you have encountered this kind of problem , please help me . Thank you very much